# Is there a Warhammer 40K codex/proxy for the Interex?

Tags: house-rules, warhammer-40k

The Interex appear in the first *Horus Heresy* book, *Horus Rising* as a branch of humanity heavily influenced by eldar.

I was forever saddened to hear they never made it.

Do any rules official and/or unofficial rules exist for playing as these? Also do any models/model making guides address making an army of Interex?

I would think either rules similar to the Eldar or Tau would fit, but I have no idea if that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure there are no official rules, but a couple of people have had a go at putting together [an unofficial codex](http://www.warseer.com/forums/showthread.php?t=91372) which looks interesting.

There are a number of intriguing modeling ideas, including conversions, for the Interex in [this forum thread](http://www.warseer.com/forums/showthread.php?t=233362&page=2).

Answer (score 3):

I've seen some people (online) that play with Imperial Guard models using the Tau rulebook as a stand-in for the Interex.